# Is it possible to embed interactive html file in my xaringan presentation?

Tags: html, plotly, r-markdown, xaringan, ioslides

I'm trying to use xaringan to build a presentation, but I have a number of html files, which are interactive charts, that I need to include. I've searched everywhere and I can't find any information on this.

Using ioslides I simply put:

```
 <iframe src="myfile_bar.html"></iframe>
```

However this doesn't work with xaringan. I would like to use xaringan, but something like this might not be possible. Otherwise, I would like to just eliminate the black space at the margins of my ioslide presentation.

What I mean by this is when I knit my ioslides presentation the slides are a wide format box in the middle of my screen. I want to be able to make this full screen as I would in Beamer. Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check [here](https://pkg.garrickadenbuie.com/xaringanExtra/#/)?

Comment: @bttomio: yes, nothing there about it.